# Veeva CLM gotoSlide function

Tags: html, veeva

Please help as I am getting error of (You'll need a new app to open this veeva) on pressing the veeva:gotoSlide(slidename.zip) button.

Below the is HTML code.

```
<div class="menu-holder">
<a href="veeva:gotoSlide(slide_05.zip)" class="btn home"></a>
<a href="veeva:gotoSlide(slide_sitemap.zip)" class="btn sitemap"></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn ref"></a>
<a href="veeva:gotoSlide(slide_01.zip)" class="btn presentation"></a>
```

Comment: please provide code

Comment: Thank Sinto for quick response. I have attached the screen shot of html code.

Comment: @ShahidRafique, why not just insert the code into the question as text?

Comment: totally make sense, let me edit and paste the code as HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow this steps for gotoslide function work properly in same presentation.

HTML and javascript:

```js
function slide5() { com.veeva.clm.gotoSlide("slide_05.zip","")};
function sitemap() { com.veeva.clm.gotoSlide("slide_sitemap.zip","")};
function slide1() { com.veeva.clm.gotoSlide("slide_01.zip","")};
```

```html
<div class="menu-holder">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick = "slide5();" class="btn home"></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick = "sitemap();" class="btn sitemap"></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn ref"></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick = "slide1();" class="btn presentation"></a>
</div>
```

Add veeva javascript:
Download link for veeva js:  https://developer.veevacrm.com/api/CLMLibrary/#multichannel-crm

How gotoslide function work:
https://developer.veevacrm.com/api/CLMLibrary/#gotoslide-key-presentation

Thanks
mbrmusa

Comment: You might also want to add the line -
    document.ontouchmove = function(event){event.preventDefault();}
above the JS code in your answer.